# How can it be done?

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy, phone

In the UK, under the Snoopers Charter, how can the police hack into your phone?

What would they see and how can it be done?

Can it be done to any phone model?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because **how to do it technically** (and what they can see) is part of data security.SE, while **how to do so legally** is the only thing that matters for law.SE.

Comment: The legal interpretation of "how" is e.g. "by getting a warrant", "by asserting a need".... We needn't interpret the question as being about technology.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. Once you've received an answer, deletion is not recommended and vandalism is never an option.

Answer (score 2):

[The law](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2016/25) is kind of humongous, but the main answer is that the law does not care about what kind of device information might be on, so it could be a phone, a computer, or something else. It basically lets the government intercept communications, if certain conditions are met. This includes stored communications, e.g. texts that you have already received on your phone. They have to have "lawful authority" which is spelled out in §6. That means either a warrant (they have a commission with a judge who can issue warrants), or authority under §§44–52, or with "statutory power that is exercised for the purpose of obtaining information or taking possession of any document or other property", or under court order. The various provisions of §§44–52 require either consent by a party, interception in connection with being a telecommunications company, "special" circumstances such as being in a mental hospital or prison. They can also compel a communications service provider to cooperate. Connection records, for example, do not require a warrant. With a warrant, if they (technologically) can remotely and secretly read your SMS's, there is a legal path allowing them to do so.